What would be a proper way of implementing this riemann gradient?
So here’s a toy example from this paper,Automatic differentiation for Riemannian optimization on low-rank matrix and tensor-train manifolds:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

def f(X):
    return torch.sum(X**2)

def g(delta_U, delta_V, U, V, f):
    perturbed_matrix = U @ delta_V.t() + delta_U @ V.t()
    return f(perturbed_matrix)

def compute_riemannian_gradient(X):
    U, S, V = torch.svd(X)
    delta_U = U @ torch.diag(S)
    delta_V = torch.zeros_like(V)
    delta_U.requires_grad_(True)
    delta_V.requires_grad_(True)
    perturbed_value = g(delta_U, delta_V, U, V, f)
    perturbed_value.backward()

    return delta_U.grad, delta_V.grad

def apply_gauge_conditions(delta_U, delta_V, V):
    delta_V -= V @ (V.t() @ delta_V)
    return delta_U, delta_V

def riemannian_gradient(X):
    U, _, V = torch.svd(X)
    delta_U, delta_V = compute_riemannian_gradient(X)
    delta_U, delta_V = apply_gauge_conditions(delta_U, delta_V, V)
    return delta_U @ V.t() + U @ delta_V.t()

X = torch.randn(5, 3)
y = X**2 + 0.1*torch.randn_like(X)
rgrad = riemannian_gradient(X)

for i in range(10):
    rgrad = riemannian_gradient(X)
    X = X - 0.01*rgrad
    # X = retraction(X, rgrad, 0.01)
    print(f(X))

So as you can see, in the training inference, I don’t need the gradient of X, or [U, S, V]. Instead, I need the gradient from delta_U and delta_V to update X. Therefore I'm not able to simply loop through the parameters registered in parameters if I want to integrate this piece of code into torch.optimizer module.
My question is what’s the proper way of implementing this optimizing algorithm in optim.step() function when the weight X is updated by gradients from other parameters?

I do not understand what you mean by "training inference", and overall, the question needs more clarity.
As I understand from a quick look at the paper, they provide you with a special algorithm to compute derivatives of low-rank matrices.
In Torch, you can define a custom function with a forward and backward method using torch.autograd.Function as succinctly described in this gist. Refer to official documentation for an extensive overview.
This class should handle the gradient computation step while the optimizer will be instantiated with [X] as the list of variable to optimize on.

Hi! Thanks for the reply! The idea of the algorithm is that you can calculate the rgrad(riemann gradient) on X, which in my case is the weight of a network, via grad on delta_V and delta_U(equation 4.7 and 4.8), meanwhile avoiding the full matrix on X. So in the training phase, in forward pass you would need the grad on delta_U and delta_V, where they are not in the same forward pass as X. And I want to put the update part of the code into torch.optimizer.step() function.

However it's hard to get the grads from other parameters in step function, because you usually loop through the parameters registered with the optimizer. Sorry if I made myself unclear.

I see you are calling backwards() on delta_U and delta_V, inside your Riemann gradient function. What instead you should do is use torch.autograd.primitves which help you get gradients but doesn't populate the grad attribute. Once you do that you can wrap the entire thing in custom forward and backward function on X as described in the docs.
